# How to get a slice from an Iterator?

Tags: rust

I started to use clippy as a linter. Sometimes, it shows this warning:

```
writing `&Vec<_>` instead of `&[_]` involves one more reference and cannot be
used with non-Vec-based slices. Consider changing the type to `&[...]`,
#[warn(ptr_arg)] on by default
```

I changed the parameter to a slice but this adds boilerplate on the call side. For instance, the code was:

```
let names = args.arguments.iter().map(|arg| {
    arg.name.clone()
}).collect();
function(&names);
```

but now it is:

```
let names = args.arguments.iter().map(|arg| {
    arg.name.clone()
}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
function(&names);
```

otherwise, I get the following error:

```
error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type
`[collections::string::String]` [E0277]
```

So I wonder if there is a way to convert an `Iterator` to a `slice` or avoid having to specify the `collect`ed type in this specific case.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> So I wonder if there is a way to convert an `Iterator` to a `slice`

There is not.

An iterator only provides one element at a time, whereas a slice is about getting several elements at a time. This is why you first need to collect all the elements yielded by the `Iterator` into a contiguous array (`Vec`) before being able to use a slice.

The first obvious answer is not to worry about the slight overhead, though personally I would prefer placing the type hint next to the variable (I find it more readable):

```
let names: Vec<_> = args.arguments.iter().map(|arg| {
    arg.name.clone()
}).collect();
function(&names);
```

Another option would be for `function` to take an `Iterator` instead (and an iterator of references, at that):

```
let names = args.arguments.iter().map(|arg| &arg.name);
function(names);
```

After all, iterators are more general, and you can always "realize" the slice inside the function if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

> So I wonder if there is a way to convert an Iterator to a slice

There is. (in applicable cases)

Got here searching "rust iter to slice", for my use-case, there was a solution:

```
fn main() {
  // example struct
  #[derive(Debug)]
  struct A(u8);

  let list = vec![A(5), A(6), A(7)];

  // list_ref passed into a function somewhere ...
  let list_ref: &[A] = &list;
  let mut iter = list_ref.iter();

  // consume some ...
  let _a5: Option<&A> = iter.next();

  // now want to eg. return a slice of the rest
  let slice: &[A] = iter.as_slice();

  println!("{:?}", slice); // [A(6), A(7)]
}
```

That said, `.as_slice` is defined on an iter of an existing slice, so the previous answerer was correct in that if you've got, eg. a map iter, you would need to collect it first (so there is something to slice from).

docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#method.as_slice