# Is it possible to flatten Vec<&[u8]> into &[u8] without copying the data?

Tags: rust

I want to flatten a vector containing `&[u8]`:

```
fn main() {
    let x: &[u8] = &b"abc"[..];
    let y: &[u8] = &b"def"[..];
    
    let z: Vec<&[u8]> = vec![x, y];
    
    println!("z: {:?}", z);
    
    let z_flat: &[u8] = z.into_iter().flatten().collect();
    
    println!("z_flat: {:?}", z_flat);
}
```

I get the compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `&[u8]` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&u8`
 --> src/main.rs:9:49
  |
9 |     let z_flat: &[u8] = z.into_iter().flatten().collect();
  |                                                 ^^^^^^^ value of type `&[u8]` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&u8>`
  |
  = help: the trait `FromIterator<&u8>` is not implemented for `&[u8]`
```

I have also tried the following:

```
let z_flat: &[u8] = &z.into_iter().map(|x| x.to_vec()).flatten().collect();
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `[u8]` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `u8`
 --> src/main.rs:9:70
  |
9 |     let z_flat: &[u8] = &z.into_iter().map(|x| x.to_vec()).flatten().collect();
  |                                                                      ^^^^^^^ value of type `[u8]` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=u8>`
  |
  = help: the trait `FromIterator<u8>` is not implemented for `[u8]`
```

The following **does** work ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b834812fa23e9cf94e80e8ae0f8a2411)):

```
let z_flat: &[u8] = &z.concat();
```

I am not able to use `concat` in my real-world application because I am using another struct when retrieving the nested bytes (`x` and `y`) and this struct cannot implement `Copy` (only `Clone`) because it contains a `Vec<u8>` field. I have something similar to this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0a6a42d4f246d9a0381eafdd76d08a7)):

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    Bar: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn baz(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.Bar
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Foo { Bar: vec![8u8] };
    let y = Foo { Bar: vec![18u8] };

    let z: Vec<Foo> = vec![x, y];

    println!("z: {:?}", z);

    let z_flat = z
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| &x.baz()[..])
        .collect::<Vec<&[u8]>>()
        .concat();

    println!("z_flat: {:?}", z_flat);
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.Bar` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         self.Bar
  |         ^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.Bar` has type `Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:22:18
   |
22 |         .map(|x| &x.baz()[..])
   |                  ^-------^^^^
   |                  ||
   |                  |temporary value created here
   |                  returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible. By definition, a slice is *one contiguous* region of memory. You don't have that to start with, so you can't create a slice.

Your workaround copies everything into one contiguous chunk of memory, which you can then get a slice of. I'd write it something like:

```rust
let z: Vec<&[u8]> = vec![b"abc", b"def"];
let z_alloc: Vec<u8> = z.iter().flat_map(|&x| x).copied().collect();
let z_flat: &[u8] = &z_alloc;

println!("z_flat: {:?}", z_flat);
```

For your larger example:

```rust
// fn baz(self) -> Vec<u8>
let z_flat: Vec<u8> = z.into_iter().flat_map(Foo::baz).collect();
```

```rust
// fn baz(&self) -> &[u8]
let z_flat: Vec<u8> = z.iter().flat_map(Foo::baz).copied().collect();
```

See also:

- [How to get a slice from an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33189227/155423)